# "Missing there required gems" even though they are installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am getting this error when I am running `rake db:migrate`

```
Missing these required gems:                                                                                                                                                                                   
  asf-soap-adapter                                                                                                                                                                                             
  haml                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  will_paginate  = 2.3.16                                                                                                                                                                                      

You're running:                                                                                                                                                                                                
  ruby 1.9.2.290 at /home/flynn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby                                                                                                                                           
  rubygems 1.8.10 at /home/flynn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails_2.3.12, /home/flynn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global                                                                                          

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

I have tried `rake gems:install` and they do get installed, they are shown on the gem list, but for some reason this error still appears. I saw similar questions on SO, but none of those solutions worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: bundle exec rake db:migrate work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with rubygems version, after downgrading to 1.6.2 `gem update --system 1.6.2` everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `bundle install` runs without error.